# Automatically modify iptables based on Apache log data to block badly behaved clients

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, iptables

Is there any tool on Linux to automatically modify iptables so as to block a troublesome client based on an analysis of the Apache log? I help run a site that sometimes get overwhelmed by requests from a particular user. The only solution is to add an entry in iptables to block the offending client. Its usually too late by the time I can react manually - hence, I would like some rule based mechanism to modify the iptables. I would guess that some kind of fuzzly logic or statistical analysis would be necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/), which IIRC, has an Apache log checker built in.

Comment: fail2ban comes very close to doing what I want. Looks like I'll have to dig through the source a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider using iptables to rate-limit incoming connections. Which in its most basic setting will give you the ability to limit incoming connections to a number per minute.

For example, you might want to only allow 10 pings per minute from a single IP address. It does get a little more sophisticated than that, with the option to set burst limits on top of long term average limits.

Some good instructions on setting it up http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/block_brute_force_attacks_with_iptables/

Comment: Excellent - I had no idea that iptables could even do that. This could be very useful.

Comment: I'll dig out an excellent guide i read recently on it

Comment: my bookmarks

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/block_brute_force_attacks_with_iptables/

Answer (score 2):

Check out [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net).  Best log file analyzer I've used. It also supports active response based on analysis.